# Music bot not playing music on Heroku but is locally

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, discord.py

I have a music bot and it works fine. When hosted locally, the bot plays the music as it should when running the `play` command. But once I hosted the bot on Heroku, the bot only joins the voice channel but doesn't output any sound. The strangest part of all this is that Discord indicates that the bot *is* playing sounds, as you can see in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTM22.png).

How can I fix this? I feel like it has something to do with Heroku, but I don't know what. I also added this Buildpack: https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git to my app, but it's still not working.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You need to add a few more buildpacks for your music bot to work on Heroku. [Here's](https://youtu.be/u6o1yUUdc54) a video you can refer to for those buildpacks, and for overall set up of a music bot on Heroku.

Comment: Have you added the [`heroku opus`](https://github.com/xrisk/heroku-opus.git) buildpack ?

Comment: No, but after I added it, it worked. Thank you so much <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a response only took place via the comments I will summarize the whole thing again for other users.

To play music at Heroku mostly 2 buildpacks are necessary. These can be added to the corresponding app under `Settings`. The following buildpacks are needed:

1. https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest
2. https://github.com/xrisk/heroku-opus

Only then the bot will probably play music, because Heroku has its problems with FFMPEG. After you have added these two buildpacks you can select `Deploy Branch` under the category `Deploy`.

*Of course you should also add a buildpack for your system (Python, JS, etc.)*.